# Counting the most frequent word in a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, count

I am trying to construct a program that if a user enters a name, it will return the number of people with that name. If they type 'most', it will return the name used the most. I got the counting individual words part somehow, but I am not sure how to make the program define and count the most frequently appearing word.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

data = ('Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue',
        'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue',
        'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Horace', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty',
        'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Doug', 'Misty', 'Wilma', 'Jesse',
        'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty',
        'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty',
        'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy',
        'Bailey', 'Peggy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty',
        'Paris', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty Mae', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy',
        'Bart', 'Big Daddy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue',
        'LeeAnne', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue',
        'Misty', 'Rowdy', 'Billy Bob', 'Ricky', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'EvaSue', 'Mark', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty
        Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob',
        'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Rob', 'Betty Sue',
        'SuelySue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr Jr',
        'Billy Bob', 'Grady', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Louise', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue',
        'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jenny Jae', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob',
        'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty
        Sue', 'BJ', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Boris', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Pegs',
        'Misty', 'Leslie', 'James', 'Melvin', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mary
        Beth', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue',
        'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'BethAnne', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue',
        'Bett', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Raina', 'Betty Sue',
        'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mikey', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Louise Jr', 'Billy Bob',
        'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty',
        'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty
        Sue', 'Horace', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue',
        'Misty', 'Doug', 'Misty', 'Wilma', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr',
        'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue',
        'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Bailey', 'Peggy',
        'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Paris', 'Leroy',
        'Leroy', 'Misty Mae', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Bart', 'Big
        Daddy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'LeeAnne', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Rowdy',
        'Billy Bob', 'Ricky', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy
        Bob', 'EvaSue', 'Mark', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob',
        'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Rob', 'Betty Sue', 'SuelySue',
        'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty
        Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob',
        'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr Jr',
        'Billy Bob', 'Grady', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Louise', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue',
        'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jenny Jae', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob',
        'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty
        Sue', 'BJ', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Boris', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Pegs',
        'Misty', 'Leslie', 'James', 'Melvin', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mary
        Beth', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue',
        'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'BethAnne', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue',
        'Bett', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Raina', 'Betty Sue',
        'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mikey', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy
        Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob',
        'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Louise Jr', 'Billy Bob',
        'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue')

print('''Welcome to the White Valley Name Counter. Enter a name, or "most" to see what name is the most used in this great city!''')

print()
keepgoing = 'y'

while keepgoing == 'y':
    count = 0
    search = input("What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? ")
    print()
    data_list = list(data)
    if search != "most":
        print("There are {} people named {}".format(data_list.count(search),search))
        print()
    elif search == "most":
        print("{} is the most common. There are {} of them".format(
                data_list.count.most_common(data_list), search))
    keepgoing = input('''Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? ''')
    print()
```

I am trying to make the output look like this:

```
Welcome to the White Valley Name Counter. Enter a name, or "most" to see what name is the most used in this great city!

What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? john

There are 0 people named john

Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? y

What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? Betty Sue

There are 79 people named Betty Sue

Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? y

What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? most

Billy Bob is most common. There are 93 of them

Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? n
```

Comment: How is a user supposed  to search for a person named "most"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to count the number of times a name occurs that is specified by the user is pretty easy!

Let's write a little function to handle that and return the result.

```
names = ("billy","bob","pete","bob",'pete','bob');


def count_my_name(name):
    return ("The name %s occurs %s times." % (name,str(names.count(name))));
```

If we print this result with the name pete we would get the following result:

`The name pete occurs 2 times.`

Now for counting the most common name in the list, we can write another neat little function to handle that and return the result for us.

```
names = ("billy","bob","pete","bob",'pete','bob');
def get_most_common_name():
    all_names = set(names);
    most_common = max([names.count(i) for i in all_names]);
    for name in all_names:
        if names.count(name) == most_common:
            return ("The most common name is %s occuring a total of %s times." % (name,str(most_common)));
```

Which will give us the result: `The most common name is bob occuring a total of 3 times.`

Okay so now some explanation for our second function, what are we actually doing here?

Well first we grab our tuple named names, it has names in it but some of them are duplicates and we don't want to iterate over the same name multiple times.
So make a new variable called `all_names` and make a set out of that list.

sets are usefull since they will remove any duplicates for us.

Now we can count the number of times a name occurs in names using:

`most_common = max([names.count(i) for i in all_names]);`

This gives us the number of the name that occurs the most inside our tuple.
Which would be 3.

Now we simply just iterate over our set `all_names` and count how many times that name occurs in names.

If the name occurs as many times in names as our `most_common` variable we have the name that occurs the most.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter for this:

```
import collections

data = ('Billy Bob', 'Misty', …)
counts = collections.Counter(data)

# add an additional 'Misty'
counts.update(['Misty'])

# most seen name
if counts:
    name, count = counts.most_common(1)[0]
    print("most common name is {} with a count of {}".format(name, count))
else:
    print("no names available")

name = "Billy Bob"
count = counts.get(name)
if count is not None:
     print("There are {} people named {}".format(count, name))
else:
     print("There is no {}".format(name))
```